# Find predicate DayOfWeek Issue c#

Tags: c#, list, find, predicate, dayofweek

Resently I went into an issue when i try to find a specific day into a list of DayOfWeek it doesn't work well for the sunday but work for all the other days.

I did a Predicate but when i seek the sunday with it on a empty list or a list which doesn't contain sunday it's finding it.

example :

```
namespace testing1
{
    public partial class Timer : Form
    {
        public static List<dayOfWeek> day = new List<dayOfWeek>();//I can set things in it

        public Timer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Timer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(day.Count); //return 0 when I instantiate the form without inserting from an another form.

                checkBox1.Checked = day.Find((dayOfWeek d) => { return d == dayOfWeek.Monday; }) == dayOfWeek.Monday; // return false OK
                checkBox2.Checked = day.Find((dayOfWeek d) => { return d == dayOfWeek.Tuesday; }) == dayOfWeek.Tuesday; // return false OK
                checkBox3.Checked = day.Find((dayOfWeek d) => { return d == dayOfWeek.Wednesday; }) == dayOfWeek.Wednesday; // return false OK
                checkBox4.Checked = day.Find((dayOfWeek d) => { return d == dayOfWeek.Thursday; }) == dayOfWeek.Thursday; // return false OK
                checkBox5.Checked = day.Find((dayOfWeek d) => { return d == dayOfWeek.Friday; }) == dayOfWeek.Friday; // return false OK
                checkBox6.Checked = day.Find((dayOfWeek d) => { return d == dayOfWeek.Saturday; }) == dayOfWeek.Saturday; // return false OK
                checkBox7.Checked = day.Find((dayOfWeek d) => { return d == dayOfWeek.Sunday; }) == dayOfWeek.Sunday; // return true WTF ????
        }
    }
}
```

Could i have some help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DayOfWeek` is an `enum` therefore it's value type, value type variables cannot have null value, unless marked as `Nullable<>`, this means that most likely the first value in the `DayOfWeek` `enum` is *Sunday* which would be the default value, so whenever `Find` is unable to find the value, it returns the default in this case being *Sunday*.

You should instead use `Contains`:

```
day.Contains(DayOfWeek.Sunday);
//..
```

Answer (score 1):

Enums are value types, and the  [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method has the following behavior when handling lists with this kind of type (quote from MSDN):

> When searching a **list containing value types, make sure the default
>   value for the type does not satisfy the search predicate**. Otherwise,
>   there is no way to distinguish between a default value indicating that
>   no match was found and a list element that happens to have the default
>   value for the type. If the default value satisfies the search
>   predicate, use the `FindIndex` method instead.